# Is it possible to set up oauth2 authentication for the MQTT Broker Mosquitto?

Tags: oauth-2.0, mqtt, keycloak, mosquitto, sasl

I would like to authenticate MQTT clients with a keycloak server.

Does Mosquitto support that?

Comment: What research into Mosquitto's authentication options have you done before asking the question?

Comment: I read mosquittos documentation about authentication methods (https://mosquitto.org/documentation/authentication-methods/). I concluded that I need a authentication plugin supporting SASL/OAuthBearer. As far as I could tell the Dynamic-Security-Plugin and the mosquitto-go-auth plugin do not support it. I was not able to find another plugin supporting SASL/OAuthBearer. Therefore I considered writing an custom Plugin.

Comment: The following repository implements oauth2 authentication
https://github.com/gewv-tu-dresden/mosquitto-go-auth-oauth2